# Software to make illustrative videos explaining a research topic

Tags: software, audio-video-recording

What are some good (preferably open-source) software for making illustrative videos to explain one's research? I am currently looking for software to make a small video on my research topic that could complement presentation slides. The video may not delve into all technical details, but should summarise all technical content in a compact and entertaining way.

One source that I know of is [Videoscribe](http://www.sparkol.com/products/videoscribe) ([sample video](http://www.videoscribe.co/scribes#video-wSmPIBJWXGM)), but I have not tried it yet. Are there other/better alternatives, especially open-source?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a [boat-programming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14486/164022) question that's not about academia

Comment: I disagree with EnergyNumbers. I think making a video explaining a research topic is something [very relevant to academic life](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/459/workplace-se-and-boat-programming-questions) (research presentation, teaching, seminars), and unless there is another SE where this question would be obviously much more on topic, I don't see any strong reason to close it.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset [avp.se]

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: thanks for making the effort to find a more suitable SE. If the OP wants, I can migrate the question there.

Answer (score 2):

Not free or open-source, but my institution offers licenses to [Camtasia Studio](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html), which seems to be the best package out there for slidecasts/screencasts.

[Educreations](http://www.educreations.com/) is a a comparatively much simpler - and cheaper - tool that allows you to create videos but doesn't play as well with slides.

Comment: You can find here the [free or open source alternatives to Camtasia Studio](http://alternativeto.net/software/camtasia-studio/?license=opensource). You may also be interested in the [free or open source alternatives to Sony Vegas Pro](http://alternativeto.net/software/sony-vegas-pro/?license=free).

Comment: @Trylks I suppose it would be good for OP to include their OS, because being a Windows user myself, the linux-only options are always a bit of a hassle. Thanks for the lists, though. They're helpful!

Comment: I've tried some free alternatives to Camtasia - they were not worth the hassle for me - malware, poor instructions, zero support, etc. Camtasia was a good investment for me.

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine who is very good at academic video-making says he only uses iMovies these days for video editing. He uses QuickTime to capture screen and audio recordings when he needs to.